# How to display table with more than one image from postgis in mapserver?

Tags: qgis, postgis, mapserver

I have 3 tif files in one postgis(2.1.5 ver.) raster table. ( load with raster2pgsql)
And i have mapserver MapServer 6.1-dev.

I need to display table from postgis in qgis via mapserver. P.S I trying to do this like with 1 image in raster table but qgis show me just white screen :( Any suggestions?